# My taskbar gets wider when I log in to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have a simple/non-critical but really annoying issue. Every time I log in to Windows 10 (or at least after restarting my PC) the taskbar has automatically been adjusted to be wider than my preference. I've had this issue on my Dell laptop and my Macbook across multiple accounts.

I have no problem fixing the taskbar. I just right-click, deselect "lock the taskbar", and then resize it. However, is there a way I can stop it from getting wider every time I log in?

Any help/insights would be appreciated!

-Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Registry hack might help, by locking the bar after you set it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
  "TaskbarLockAll"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
  "TaskbarSizeMove"=dword:00000000
```

You can copy that into a .reg file., or manually add and/or change the two values using Regedit.

Let me know if that keeps the setting.

Comment: That worked on both computers. Thanks.